# Sending screenshot

Tags: python, typeerror

This is my code it should send me an email with a screenshot but instead I get the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "email_screenshot.py", line 34, in <module>
    my_screenshot.start()
  File "email_screenshot.py", line 26, in start
    with open(im) as file:
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, PngImageFile found
```

This is the code what should I do to get rid of the type error in this python2.7 code.

```
import pyscreenshot as ImageGrab
import smtplib
import base64


class Screenshot:
        def __init__(self, email, password):
            self.screenshot = ImageGrab.grab
            self.email = email
            self.password = password

        def send_screenshot(self):
            self.send_email(self.email, self.password, self.screenshot)
            report = self.send_screenshot
            report.start()

        def send_email(self, email, password, message):
            server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
            server.starttls()
            server.login(email, password)
            server.sendmail(email, email, message)
            server.quit()

        def start(self):
            im = ImageGrab.grab()
            with open(im) as file:
                file.write(base64.b64decode(im))
            with im:
                self.send_screenshot()
                im.join()


my_screenshot = Screenshot("myuser", "mypass",)
my_screenshot.start()
```

does anyone have any ideas

Comment: `ImageGrab.grab` doesn't return a filename, why are you trying to open it as a file?

Comment: If you need a temporary file to put an attachment in, use the `tempfile` module.

Comment: You're not calling `ImageGrab.grab` when you assign to `self.screenshot`, you're just setting it to the function.

Comment: Also, there is an undeclared variable `self.send_screenshot` used in `def send_screenshot(self)`. If it was meant to be a function call to itself, you will end up with a recursive call error.